# Invariant Violation:Tried to register two views with the same name RNCWebView

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error while running my project could anyone please let me know the solution? I have cleared the cache and Reinstalled the node_modules as well.

[image: 1]

Could anyone please let me know the solution?

Comment: can you please share the code?

Comment: Sorry, I can't Share the Code at the moment Because It's my Client's Code. If Anyone is facing this issue then please help me.

Comment: It might be because of navigation. I mean if you have two screens with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

First You have to run

npm ls react-native-webview

then see there are multiple Dependencies of react-native-webview installed on your project.

Please Run
yarn add react-native-webview-leaflet